# Can we show joint measurability of $(t,x)\mapsto(\kappa_tf)(x)$ for a Markov semigroup $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space and $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Markov semigroup on $(E,\mathcal E)$. Note that $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a contraction semigroup on $$\mathcal E_b:=\left\{f:E\to\mathbb R\mid f\text{ is bounded and }\mathcal E\text{-measurable}\right\}$$ (equipped with the supremum norm) via $$(\kappa_tf)(x):=\int\kappa_t(x,{\rm d}y)f(y)\;\;\;\text{for }f\in\mathcal E_b.$$

Now let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ which is invariant with respect to $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ and $p\ge1$. Noting that $\mathcal E_b$ is dense in $\mathcal L^p(\mu)$, we easily see that $\kappa_t$ has a unique contractive linear extension to $L^p(\mu)$ for all $t\ge0$ and $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a contraction semigroup on $L^p(\mu)$.

Assuming that $$[0,\infty)\times E\to\mathbb R\;,\;\;\;(t,x)\mapsto(\kappa_tf)(x)\tag1$$ is $\mathcal B([0,\infty))\otimes\mathcal E$-measurable for all $f\in\mathcal E_b$, are we able to show that $(1)$ and/or $$[0,\infty)\to L^p(\mu)\;,\;\;\;f\mapsto\kappa_tf\tag2$$ is $\mathcal B([0,\infty))\otimes\mathcal B(L^p(\mu))$-measurable for all $f\in L^p(\mu)$?

**EDIT**: We know that there is a nondecreasing $(f_n^\pm)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal E_b$ with $f^\pm_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}f^\pm$ and hence $$(\kappa_tf^\pm_n)(x)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}(\kappa_tf^\pm)(x)\;\;\;\text{for all }(t,x)\in[0,\infty)\times E\tag3.$$ Thus, $(1)$ is measurable for $f$ replaced by $f^\pm$.

Now, since $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu)$, we only obtain that $\mu\kappa_t|f|<\infty$ and hence $$\kappa_t|f|<\infty\;\;\;\mu\text{-almost surely}\tag4$$ for all $t\ge0$. So, $$\kappa_tf=\kappa_tf^+-\kappa_tf^-\tag5$$ does only hold up to a $\mu$-null set depending on $t\ge0$. This should prevent us from concluding the desired measurability of $(1)$, unless we are assuming that $\mathcal A$ is $\mu$-complete (or is even that not enough?).

Regarding the measurability of $(3)$, I have no idea how we could show that ...

Comment: Is that map even well-defined? What is meant by the evaluation of an element of $L^p(\mu)$ at a point $x$?

Comment: @unwissen There is no element of $L^p(\mu)$ which is evaluated at a point. Look carefully at the definition.

Comment: So what is $\kappa_t f$ then? Saying "$(\kappa_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is contraction semigroup on $L^p(\mu)$" would mean $\kappa_t \colon L^p(\mu) \to L^p(\mu)$ for me.

Comment: @unwissen Since $\mu$ is invariant with respect to $\kappa_t$, we know that $f$ is integrable with respect to $\kappa_t(x,\;\cdot\;)$ for $\mu$-almost all $x\in E$. So, $\kappa_tf$ is well-defined $\mu$-almost surely.

Comment: @unwissen In order to obtain the uniqueness claim I've made in the question, we need to restrict the target space to $L^p(\mu)$. With ths definition, $\kappa_tf$ is an element of $L^p(\mu)$ and hence we cannot evaluated it pointwisely. I agree on that. Maybe we need to ask whether $t\mapsto\kappa_tf$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal B([0,\infty))$ and $\mathcal B(L^p(\mu))$ instead?

Comment: @unwissen Please take note of my edit. BTW: What I'm actually trying to understand is why $Gf_0$ in Theorem 2.18-3) in the lecture notes "MarkovProcesses2021.pdf" here https://uni-bonn.sciebo.de/s/kzTUFff5FrWGAay#pdfviewer is actually well-defined. Maybe you can take a look.

Comment: That is in fact true if you talk about a *strongly continuous* semigroup. Indeed, then $(t, f) \mapsto T_t(f)$ is continuous (even locally uniform in $t$) as a map $[0, \infty) \times X \to X$ for every strongly continuous semigroup $(T_t)_{t \geq 0}$ on $X$.

Comment: @unwissen Yes, I know that. But which assumptino on $X$ do we need to impose in order to obtain that $(\kappa_t)$ is actually a $C^0$-semigroup on $L^p(\mu)$?

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure of this, but let me say the following concerning $G f_0$ in Theorem 2.18 of the linked notes.
It is supposed that $((X_t)_{t\geq0}, P_X)$ is a right-continuous Markov process. I'm not sure if this is actually enough to imply that $t \mapsto p_t(x, \cdot)$ is weakly continuous with the definition of Markov process with associated kernel that is in the notes or if this was intended.
Some people already define Markov kernels to be measurable in $(x, t)$.

Comment: If we assume the measurability $(x, t) \mapsto p_t(x, A)$ for all measurable $A$, then 
$$
p_t f(x) = \int \, f(y) \, p_t(x, \mathrm{d}y)
$$ is measurable in $(x, t)$ too for all $f \in L^1(\mu)$.
This can be shown by approximation by simple functions.
If we assume that the kernel is measurable in $x$ (as in your notes) but weakly continuous in $t$, then
$$
\int \, f(y) \, p_t(x, \mathrm{d}y)
$$ is continuous in $t$ and measurable in $x$ for $f \in C_{b}$, i.e. measurable in $(x, t)$. Probably possible to deduce the measurability for general $f$ by taking limits

Comment: @unwissen Thank you for your comment. Well, I think you made a slight mistake. If $(x, t) \mapsto p_t(x, A)$ is measurable for all measurable $A$, then $(x,t)\mapsto(p_tf)(x)$ is measurable for all *bounded* measurable $f$ too. But it's precisely my question whether it is measurable for all $f\in L^1(\mu)$ as well. We can clearly approximate $f\in L^1(\mu)$ by a sequence of bounded measurable functions (the approximation can be done wrt the $L^p(\mu)$-norm or pointwisely; one what did you thought about?), but how do you conclude the desired measurability from that?

Comment: It is $p_t(f)(x) = p_t(f^{+})(x) - p_t(f^{-})(x)$ and as positive measurable functions $g$ are increasing limits of simple functions, we have by monotone convergence that $p_t g(x)$ is a pointwise (i.e. for fixed $(x, t)$) limit of measurable functions and therefore measurable.

Comment: @unwissen Please take note of my edit. I think there is a subtlety you are missing.